# Copy a categorical variable with its value labels

Tags: copy, stata, categorical-data

Is it possible to copy a labeled categorical variable in a single line, or do I generally have to copy over labels as a separate step?

In the case I'm looking at, `egen ... group()` comes close, but changes the underlying integers:

```
sysuse auto

** starts them from different indices
egen mycut = cut(mpg), at(0 20 30 50) label icodes
egen mycut_copy = group(mycut), label

** does weird stuff
egen mycut2 = cut(mpg), at(0 20 30 50) label icodes
replace mycut2 = group(mycut2)
egen mycut_copy2 = group(mycut2), label

** the correct approach?
gen mycut3 = cut(mpg), at(0 20 30 50) label icodes
gen mycut_copy3 = mycut3
label values mycut_copy3 mycut3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want very easily using the less-known `clonevar` command:

```
sysuse auto, clear

egen mycut = cut(mpg), at(0 20 30 50) label icodes
clonevar mycut2 = mycut

list mycut* in 1/10, separator(0)

     +----------------+
     | mycut   mycut2 |
     |----------------|
  1. |   20-      20- |
  2. |    0-       0- |
  3. |   20-      20- |
  4. |   20-      20- |
  5. |    0-       0- |
  6. |    0-       0- |
  7. |   20-      20- |
  8. |   20-      20- |
  9. |    0-       0- |
 10. |    0-       0- |
     +----------------+
```

Note that `group()` refers to different functions when used with `generate` and `egen`, which is why you do not get the same results.